# Typescript - variables declaration

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm not sure if this is the place for this question, but I've been told code review is not the place for it.

I'm just learning Angular 2 and Typescript, so am working through this following tutorial:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html

Between part three and four, the declaration of the `heroes` variable in the `app.component.ts` changes from:

```
export class AppComponent {
    heroes = HEROES;
}
```

to:

```
export class AppComponent {
    heroes: Hero[];
}
```

I understand the first one sets it to a constant of heroes array but why does the second one use a colon and not just set it to an empty array?

Changing the second one to an `=` actually throws an expression expected error so basically I'm just trying to understand the differences between the two.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
heroes: Hero[];
```

doesn't set it to a value.
It just defines a property with

- name = `heroes`
- type = `Hero[]` which means array of `Hero`
- without assigning a value which keeps it at default value `null`.

With initialization it would look like

```
heroes: Hero[] = [new Hero('Spidey'), new Hero('Batman')];
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean with the number. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the two is that the first one is javascript, you are assigning your **heroes** variable to the constant **HEROES*.

The second one it's a typescript thing, you are saying that the **heroes** variable will be an array of heroes, basically you are defining an empty variable.

It's like java or c# where you do something like `public int myNumber` on your class

Comment: Nice, I like the c# comparison - I guess that's what threw me as I know it's being converted to js, I thought that it was also setting the variable as js doesn't have strongly typed variables in that sense

Answer (score 1):

Your first understanding is right with:

```
heroes = HEROES
```

Now:

```
heroes : Hero [ ];
```

Here `Hero`  represents a class which holds certain properties. By this line, you are telling the TypeScript compiler that the `heroes` variable will hold a list of objects having type of `Hero` (custom or user defined type). In OOP world `class` is a user defined dataType and accordingly you can declare any variable with that Type.

Please note, you can declare (:) any variable with Type, you can't assign (=) Type (in TypeScript) but you can assign that Type of data to variable.

So here you can't use `=`.

Answer (score 0):

Just complementing @Günter Zöchbauer,

in class/interface declarations, `:` after a property name is used to define its type.

However, this might cause a little confusion when you're creating an object on-the-fly, which, in this case, `:` marks value assignment:

```
interface MyInterface {
  myBooleanProperty: boolean = false;
}

// ... somewhere

let a = {
  myBooleanProperty: true
};

// and to add a little more fun

let b: MyInterface = {
  myBooleanProperty: true
}
```