# How does this strange JavaScript code work? Mystery colon

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'm following the official Angular 2 tutorial and then I saw this piece of code:

**`const HEROES: Hero[] = ...`**

I don't understand how the colon can be after HEROES, I can't find any documentation on this colon usage in JavaScript and TypeScript. I thought the colon were only used in object "key: value" and ternary operators.

```
export class Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

const HEROES: Hero[] = [
  { id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice' },
  { id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
  { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
  { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' },
  { id: 15, name: 'Magneta' },
  { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' },
  { id: 17, name: 'Dynama' },
  { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ' },
  { id: 19, name: 'Magma' },
  { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }
];
```

Can you help me understand this colon syntax?

The other questions answer does not explain about typescript and that it is a special syntax.

Comment: Is a const that contain  an array and the collon is the separator for array element .. each element is an object

Comment: HEROES: Hero[] is just the way you specify the type of a variable in TypeScript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript - variables declaration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39832298/typescript-variables-declaration)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is TypeScript code, and this is how you declare (annotate) the [type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html) of a variable in TypeScript. The declaration means that the type of `HEROES` should be `Hero[]`, an array of `Hero` objects.

```
var HEROES: Hero[];
```

The TypeScript compiler will use this information to prevent incorrect assignments to this variable -- for example, you cannot assign a `number` to `HEROES` *(not just because the latter is a constant in your code, but because it would be a type-error)*.

---

Type declarations can be found in strong-typed programming languages; for example, an equivalent in C# would be:

```
Hero[] HEROES;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is basic typescript declaration and initilaization. refer to this link for more details

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html

Answer (score 1):

```
const HEROES: Hero[] = [
...
];
```

The `:` is a way to specify the type of a variable in TypeScript language, here HEROES is an Array of Hero instance.

This notation is called type annotation, refer [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/tutorial.html).